# Using ImageTk PhotoImage .paste() method yields AttributeError

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on an application using tkinter that will allow users to collect data from an image. Right now, I'm trying to allow a user to draw a line across the image to specify from where the data will be collected. It seems that there are a number of ways to draw a line in this way, but I'm trying to use the `PhotoImage` object's `.paste()` method.

Here are the relevant sections of code:

```
import openpyxl, PIL.Image, sys, openpyxl, glob, numpy
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(object):

    instructions = ['Draw line within ventral patch', 'Draw line within eye ring',
                    'Draw line from eye ring to face', 
                    'Draw proximal line from dorsal patch to ventral patch', 
                    'Draw medial line from dorsal patch to ventral patch',
                    'Draw distal line from dorsal patch to ventral patch'
                    ]

    NUMSTEPS = len(instructions)

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.root = root
        w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth() * .9, root.winfo_screenheight() * .9
        root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

        root.title('Squirrel Project')
        root.wm_iconbitmap('Squirrel.ico')

        instruction = Label(root, text = self.instructions[self.getStep()])
        instruction.pack(side = TOP)

        im = self.getImage()
        imageViewer = Label(root)
        imageViewer.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
        root.update()
        imageViewerSize = [imageViewer.winfo_height(), imageViewer.winfo_width()]
        im = self.imageResize(im, imageViewerSize)

        self.im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        im = self.im

        imageViewer = Label(root, image = im, cursor = 'cross')
        root.update()
        imageViewer.image = im

        imageViewer.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.drawTempLine)

        imageViewer.pack()


        buttonFrame = Frame(root, width = w, height = 25, padx = 15, pady = 15, relief = 'raised')
        buttonFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)

        saveButton = Button(buttonFrame, text = 'Confirm', command = self.save, padx = 30)
        saveButton.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 60)

        undoButton = Button(buttonFrame, text = 'Undo', command = self.undo, padx = 30)
        undoButton.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = 60)

        colorArray = numpy.array(([0], [0], [255]), dtype = int) 
        pixIm = Image.fromarray(colorArray)
        self.pixIm = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pixIm)

    def getImage(self):
        files = [file for file in glob.glob('C://Users/Alec/Desktop/Squirrels/Smithsonian/lateral/*.jpg')]

        counter = 0
        seen = []
        for x in range(1, self.sheet.max_row):
            Id = self.sheet.cell(row = x, colun = 1).value
            seen.append(Id)    

        for file in files:
            counter += 1
            if file not in seen:
                break

        im = file
        im = Image.open(im)

        return im

    def imageResize(self, image, constraint):
        actualSize = [image.height, image.width]

        if actualSize[0] > actualSize[1]:
            factor = constraint[0] / actualSize[0]
        else: 
            factor = constraint[1] / actualSize[1]

        newSize = [value * factor for value in actualSize]
        image.thumbnail(tuple(newSize))
        return image

    def getStep(self):
        return 0

    def drawTempLine(self, event):
        self.im.paste(self.pixIm, (event.x - 1, event.y - 1, event.x + 1, event.y + 1))


app = Tk()
App(app)

app.mainloop()
```

This results in the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Alec/Contrast App.py", line 146, in drawTempLine
    self.im.paste(self.pixIm, (event.x - 1, event.y - 1, event.x + 1, event.y + 1))
  File "C:\Users\Alec\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 177, in paste
    im.load()
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'load'
```

What's the cause of this attribute error and how can I correct it?

Comment: Please post the error. Also, please reduce the amount of code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with a method on an object, we really only need that object, and enough code to duplicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

`Image` has the paste method, not `PhotoImage`.

You need to modify the image and then re-convert it to a PhotoImage to display it.

We can't help with your code unless you show a **complete** example, as in one that we can run.